# Ruby Gem not working in C9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, cloud9-ide

I'm trying to write a program that can enter data into a fillable pdf.  I've installed the gem per the instructions on the github [pdf-forms](https://github.com/jkraemer/pdf-forms).

I put the `require pdf-forms` statement at the top of my file but when I try to run the program, I get this:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/pdf-forms-0.6.0/lib/pdf_forms/pdftk_wrapper.rb:18:in `initialize': pdftk executable #!/usr/local/bin/pdftk not found (RuntimeError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/pdf-forms-0.6.0/lib/pdf_forms.rb:15:in `new'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/pdf-forms-0.6.0/lib/pdf_forms.rb:15:in `new'
        from formfill.rb:3:in `<main>
```

I can't find the /usr/ folder in the IDE and wanted to know how to get this set up properly.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You may forgot to install `pdftk`,

Either get a binary package from http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/ and install it, or run

```
  apt-get install pdftk
```

if you're on Debian or similar.

Comment: It's installed.  I'm just not sure how to get around the whole /usr/ path thing because that isn't a path in a C9 workspace

sudo apt-get install pdftk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
pdftk is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.

Comment: Oh, so its installation look ok. Try to restart your server. And yes i have tried in my system in console and its working. So good luck buddy.

Comment: Did you pick a specific path when you installed it?  I've restarted and I'm still getting the same error that it can't find itself

Comment: Nothing as simply as written on gem page. Are you able to find `pdftk -version` (execute it in console). If not then problem is in your installation. Because till by seeing your error its look that `pdftk` command is not found in your system.